# Pandas: Separate two columns with missing separator

Tags: python, pandas, formatting, time-series, separator

i have data like:

```
00052600150.00942615
00052601000.01014910
00052601050.02709672
00052601100.11454732
00052601150.23151254
00052601200.36262522
00052601250.66432348
00052601301.07723763
00052601351.26019487
00052601401.20568581
```

First 10 digits represent the timestep YYMMDDhhmm followed by a number

Its supposed to be 0005260010,0.00799872 where the first block is a timestep and the second a measurement.

Ive tried to read the data with pandas and convert it to a str but then i loose the leading zeros? Is there a way to separate a float by digit?

greetings

Comment: timestep - you mean timestamp? if so - those are fixed length, so cmon man...

Comment: hi, nope it varies

Comment: @Mainzelmann - Please include the known variations in you example data to avoid confusion.

Comment: the length of the timestep (like 5 min/10 min etc.) varies, but its always 10 digits. I will add that to the question sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the column as `str` and split your value by positions

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourfile.csv', header=None, dtype='str', names=['col1'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df.col1.str[:10], unit='s')
df['value'] = (df.col1.str[10:]).astype('float')
df
```

Out:

```
                   col1                time     value
0  00052600150.00942615 1970-03-02 21:06:55  0.009426
1  00052601000.01014910 1970-03-02 21:08:20  0.010149
2  00052601050.02709672 1970-03-02 21:08:25  0.027097
3  00052601100.11454732 1970-03-02 21:08:30  0.114547
4  00052601150.23151254 1970-03-02 21:08:35  0.231513
5  00052601200.36262522 1970-03-02 21:08:40  0.362625
6  00052601250.66432348 1970-03-02 21:08:45  0.664323
7  00052601301.07723763 1970-03-02 21:08:50  1.077238
8  00052601351.26019487 1970-03-02 21:08:55  1.260195
9  00052601401.20568581 1970-03-02 21:09:00  1.205686
```

Comment: oh dude thanks, i did not read in the data as dtype=str and instead reformatted the data after reading it and lost the number format. That way the split works without problems!

Answer (score 0):

A regex with pandas can split your column without delimeters

```py
# sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [
    '00052600150.00942615',
    '00052601000.01014910',
    '00052601050.02709672',
    '00052601100.11454732',
    '00052601150.23151254',
    '00052601200.36262522',
    '00052601250.66432348',
    '00052601301.07723763',
    '00052601351.26019487',
    '00052601401.20568581',
]})

df3 = df['A'].str.extract(
    r'(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d\.\d*)',
    expand=True)
df3.columns = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Minute', 'Reading']
print(df3)
```

Output

```
  Year Month Day Hour Minute     Reading
0   00    05  26   00     15  0.00942615
1   00    05  26   01     00  0.01014910
2   00    05  26   01     05  0.02709672
3   00    05  26   01     10  0.11454732
4   00    05  26   01     15  0.23151254
5   00    05  26   01     20  0.36262522
6   00    05  26   01     25  0.66432348
7   00    05  26   01     30  1.07723763
8   00    05  26   01     35  1.26019487
9   00    05  26   01     40  1.20568581
```